# Maya.env custom ['MAYA_SCRIPT_PATH']

Tags: environment-variables, maya

I have created a project in my userFolder:

> /Users/Goffer/myRig

In my Maya.env, I have added the following lines:

```
SHARED_MAYA_DIR = HostName:/Users/Goffer
MAYA_SCRIPT_PATH = $SHARED_MAYA_DIR/myRig
```

In Maya, when I print `os.environ['MAYA_SCRIPT_PATH']`

I can see my folder as:

```
HostName:/Users/Goffer/myRig
```

Then, when I try to import a module:

```
import myRig.utils.qtUtils
```

it says:

> Error: ImportError: file  line 1: No module named
>   myRig.utils.qtUtils

I have an `__ init__.py` in each one of my folders.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to check the paths that Python is pointed to in order to see if it sees your directory.

```
import sys
for path in sys.path:
    print path
```

If your directory is not there you need to add your path to `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, since `MAYA_SCRIPT_PATH` is for mel scripts (Correct me if I'm wrong!).

You can also check the paths that are in `PYTHONPATH` like this.

```
for path in os.getenv('PYTHONPATH').split(':'): # May need to split with ';' depending on what OS you're in
    print path
```

Comment: Oh wait ... if I inlcude the folder 'myRig' in my path. I don t have to call it in my import ... it works with import utils.qtUtils. Thanks for your help, my folder was missing from PYTHONPATH too. But I thought that by adding it to MAYA_SCRIPT_PATH it would add it to PYTHONPATH. I think I ve seen this on a blog...